# Print buffer in gdb relative to register

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

In GDB when I want to print 10 bytes from r1 register :

```
x/10x $r1
```

But how can I print number of bytes that store in `r5` register?

```
x/$r5 $r1
```

Is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDB parses the *count* portion of the *FMT* argument to `x` as a string of digits (whatever the C *atoi* function accepts). To insert the integer value of a register - or any other expression - there, you can use `eval`:

```
eval "x/%dxb $r1", $r5
```